# How can I get target from focus event as a HTMLElement?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm working with angular-material mat-checkbox, inside the checkbox I have some focusable elements. My goal is to style them according to design.

I want to get target element from FocusEvent, check its tag name or/and class, then append/remove another class to it.

My problem is that I can't properly deal with Typescript. FocusEvent has target property, but it is of EventTarget type, which has only three methods. I can't get HTMLElement from this EventTarget.

Please, advise me, what is the right Typescript way to fix it.
My code is:

Template:

```
(focusout)="onFocusOut($event.target)"
```

Controller:

```
onFocusOut(target: HTMLElement): void {
    if (target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
      // some logic here
    }
  }
```

IDE marks `$event.target` as of wrong type, `EventTarget` is not `HTMLElement`.

Comment: HTMLInputElement..?

Comment: Try using @ViewChild (or @ViewChildren) depending on your requirement.

Comment: If you're using Angular Material, adding the ```focusout``` with the event target inside the ```mat-checkbox``` tag and it does not return a ```HTMLElement``` or ```HTMLInputElement``` then you have an error in your code. However, without additional information it cannot be resolved.

Comment: Try `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MrRobot, I've done it via @ViewChild. Solution changed a bit, but works. For my purpose it was enough to get input element within mat-checkbox. As I got it, I checked document.activeElement === hiddenMatInput, so I can apply my logic relatively to focused element.
PS: Both event.currentTarget and event.target are absent in FocusEvent.